# Suppress Warning: "Usage of package `fancyhdr' together(scrbook) with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended."

Tags: packages, koma-script, scrbook, silence

I am using a titlepage, that causes the following error:

> Usage of package `fancyhdr' together(scrbook) with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.

It appears to work fine, and I don't use package `fancyhdr` anywhere outside the titlepage. So I don't really need to fix the warning, instead I would like to supress it.

The only way I know to supress warnings in LaTeX is the `silence` package, but as far as I can tell, I always need to specify which package causes the exception.

How do I suppress this warning?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx), Simon.  In order to help you, you should always include a MWE (Minimal Working Example), which starts with `\documentclass` and ends in `\end{document}`.  In your case, it is likely, that you can achieve the same effect, you got with `fancyhdr` by using KOMA-Scripts own mechanisms.  Therefore a more elaborated description would also be helpful for you.  Maybe you don't even need to suppress anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `silence` package you mention works just fine:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{scrbook}{Usage of package `fancyhdr'}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I was not aware it was scrbook throwing the warning and not latex itself.

Comment: That solution works and is a straight way to keep one's personal mental health. :D